# Which bibliography style gives me author names formatted say as, Hazard BD?

Tags: bibtex

To be clear:
I want Hazard BD, not Hazard, B.D.
Citations of this type are found in the Elsevier Journal, Communications in Nonlinear Sciences and Numerical Simulations.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/19384) In most cases a complete [Minimal Working Example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/19384) that clearly shows your problem would be useful. It would at least be useful to know what bibliography styles etc you are currently using.

Comment: After looking at the [guidelines](http://www.elsevier.com/journals/communications-in-nonlinear-science-and-numerical-simulation/1007-5704/guide-for-authors#68000), the abbreviated first names should contain a period for this journal.

Comment: Please edit your question, and/or answer it yourself. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

- As I pointed out in the comments, the [guidelines](http://www.elsevier.com/journals/communications-in-nonlinear-science-and-numerical-simulation/1007-5704/guide-for-authors#68000) of that journal require periods in first name abbreviations, so I am not sure whether you still want that.
- Omitting the periods is IMHO bad typographical style, so I am not sure whether you *should* want that.
- That said, if you insist on that, make a copy of a bibtex style that comes closest to what you want, say `myplain.bst`. Open it, and locate the function `format.names`, where a string like `"{ff~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}"` is to be found. Replace that string with `"{vv~}{ll}{, jj}{, f{}}"`, and save your new style. Explanation: the final `{, f{}}` part tells BibTeX to put the first names last, in abbreviated form, and without period. The pair of braces `{}` after the `f` suppresses spaces between the initials.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) and its `fistinits=true,terseinits=true` options.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[firstinits=true,terseinits=true]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Hazard, Benjamin D.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]